# 15A 125V smart plug being used to slow charge electric car

Tags: battery-charging, electric-vehicle

So my car is using a charger that from what I'm told is both level 1 and level 2 capable. What I'm getting from the car is that its slowly drawing 8A continuously untill charged. The plug I have in the wall is a standard NEMA 5-15 120V 15A plug that has an adapter that adapts it to the NEMA 6-20 240V 20A plug to fit the charger. I bought a smart plug that is rated 125V 15A to be able to beat the variable peak hours my company sends out. My question is will this thing melt? So the charger from what I read adapts to what the socket is in terms of power draw same as the car and the car is only set to 8A 120V draw. Is this going to work?

Comment: "I bought a smart plug that is rated 125V 15A" - which smart plug is it?

Comment: Using an adaptor to increase the current rating sounds bad. Sounds like the smartplug is really smart. Fit a new properly rated supply to get the fasrer charge rate, and « fit » means use a professional electrician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
*NEMA 6-15 duplex recep does not approve.*

### Nope.  Nope.

Take that NEMA 5-15 to 6-20 adapter **and throw it in the trash**. What are you thinking?

Have you deliberately wired 240V to a common NEMA 5-15 socket? No, that's unbelievably dangerous.  Get the correct 240V socket (one such pictured above, they also make a near identical NEMA 6-20 20A version).

Plug your charger into that, like it's made to.

As far as smart-switching it...

### Kitbash this out of UL-listed stuff. It's not hard.

All you need to do is get a "RIB" Relay In Box type of product.  It's actually made for use in mains wiring, it has a **UL listing** instead of *ЯU*.  It mounts in a junction box knockout. They also make contactors that mount on a junction box cover.

[image]

Select a 240V relay/contactor (honestly, I could care less if it's 2-pole) that has a 120V relay **coil**.  In the junction box where you mount it, come out of that with conduit to *right next to* an *actual* 120V receptacle.  There, you fit a common 120V NEMA 5-15 **[inlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHVOS.jpg)**.  Get it?

The wiring is simple: from the 120V inlet hot/neutral to the relay coil.

Now, plug an extension cord from the inlet to the outlet that's right there.  The relay picks up and powers up the EVSE. Getting the picture?

**Now, where the extension cord's plug meets the ordinary NEMA 5-15 outlet, you put your smart switch *there***.

Another option is to use the very common/cheap 24V contactors that mount in knockouts or box lids. They have strict separation of 240V from 24V.  For that, still use your smart switch, but plug a 24V transformer into the smart switch output. Basically the same deal, except you get to use cheap thermostat wire and informal wiring methods because it's low voltage and thus mostly harmless.